# Ruta archivo JDK en Linux Mint

Tags: java, linux, vscode, xpath

Tengo entendido que Linux Mint viene con Java 11 por defecto, y necesito usar Java en Visual Studio Code, el problema es que me está pidiendo la ruta del archivo JDK para poder usarlo y no soy capaz de encontrar la ruta adecuada. El error que me sale es `Java 8 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK.`

Tengo que añadir la ruta al archivo `settings.conf` de Visual Studio Code, pero no me da por válida ninguna de las que he probado.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado de `$ which javac`?

Comment: El resultado es: `/usr/bin/javac`

Comment: Seguramente es un symbolic link, síguelo.

Comment: Me lleva hasta `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin`

Comment: Puedes usar esa ruta, aunque habrás notado es Java 8.

Comment: Me he dado cuenta de que es java 8, sí, pero lo prefiero por que java 11 me daba problemas a veces. La cosa es que si pongo la ruta me sale el siguiente error:
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/ CurrentInvalid
This path is not pointing to a JDK. Try remove the "bin" from the path.`.


He probado también a poner la ruta `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac` y me sale el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

Debería funcionar si pones en settings.json:

```
"java.home":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64",
```

La ruta del JAVA_HOME es el directorio "padre" del "bin", es decir, la ruta de instalación del JDK (o JRE si fuera el caso). El error que te daba iba por ahí.

Comment: Tampoco me funciona, me aparece el mismo error.

Comment: @JuanGracia, ¿ lo estás añadiendo a la "key" "java-home" ?

Comment: Estoy poniendo lo siguiente `"java.home":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"`. Esto al final del documento `settings.json`.